# Problems related to breathable liquid and deep sea diving

Tags: worldbuilding-process

I was reading a bit over the idea of modifying a human to be able to withstand diving great depths/adequately function underwater and the mention of a lung filled with per-fluorocarbon and a machine surgically attached to the human to assist with pumping the liquid in and out the necessary pathways to maintain an healthy level of oxidation in the blood stream. While the idea seemed great at first however no one really seemed to think of the ideas of the density of the liquid in your lungs. Water has a density of 1g/mL, per-fluorocarbon has a density of 1.9g/mL, nearly double. Wouldn't this have a similar effect in destabilizing the body's equilibrium with the surrounding water? Also, you have to think about the material of the diving apparatus and pumping machine. Wouldn't they also crush at high pressures underwater?

Comment: Seems more like a question for Physics.

Answer (score 1):

An object's density only affects its buoyancy. not its ability to withstand pressure.  The reason to use a liquid like perflourocarbons is because it doesn't compress under the extreme pressure like a gas would.  The fact that it's much more dense than the water just makes the diver prone to sinking.

As far as the material of the diving apparatus, again, the design is such that all of the open spaces would be fluid-filled, either open to the outside water or containing the perfluorocarbon or some other liquid at equal pressure.  Either way, the materials are seeing the same pressure from all directions and thus will not be crushed (provided that they're solid enough to not collapse in on themselves like styrofoam).

Comment: Note to myself: never eat bean before deep diving, might finish by having fart gases dissolved in the bloodstream.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi the human body is blessed with multiple orifices for ridding itself of gas-phase metabolic wastes. Just make sure you open your drysuit _outside_ when you get back to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

The problems with breathable liquid deep diving is not a bouyancy or structural stability, but dissoleved gases. Mostly important - oxigen, CO2, nitrogen in that order.
When pressure rises their partial pressure rises also. This makes chemical reaction go in wrong ways or at wrong speeds. So main problems are:

1. Oxygen toxicity -  makes person "drunk", leads to hypercapnia
2. Hypercapnia ,too much CO2 in blood (yes, *simultaneously with* oxygen toxicity)  - headaches, psychosis
3. Decompression sickness even with slight depth changes or even by currents (they reduce pressure due to Bernoulli effect)

So we have a irrational, excited diver with tunnel vision, headaches and pain all over his body. This state lead to countless deaths already (since diver don't even try to save himself and did quite suicidal actions).

While it is relativly easy to remove nitrogen, oxigen and CO2 are always there and regadless of methods of pressure compensation only srict complaince to diving procedures can help.

Comment: I presume a breathing device should keep these concentrations in check.

Comment: @Alexander, no device can change concentration of gases in tissues and cells directly. And it takes spesific times for biological matter to manage this concentrations. So this device is more usefull as monitor - for diver to know if he is doing smth wrong.

Comment: But this problem is not in any way inherent in liquid breathing - it would be common for humans even if we can entirely bypass the lungs. What's attractive it liquid breathing idea is that we don't have to fiddle with exact proportion of trimix and heliox.

Answer (score 1):

> a lung filled with per-fluorocarbon and a machine surgically attached to the human to assist with pumping the liquid in and out

If you're going to surgically attach stuff, might I suggest instead that you fill the lungs with some inert fluid, and use [ECMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extracorporeal_membrane_oxygenation) to do gas exchange instead? It saves a lot of wear and tear pumping stuff in and out of relatively delicate lung tissues all the time, and uses a technology which is already available and seems likely to get better in the future?

> Water has a density of 1g/mL, per-fluorocarbon has a density of 1.9g/mL, nearly double. Wouldn't this have a similar effect in destabilizing the body's equilibrium with the surrounding water?

Divers already have to deal with density differences, and do so by carrying weights. If your chest isn't full of air, the amount of weight you'll need is much less. Your trim might be somewhat different in the water, but either trim weights can be added to the lower body to compensate, or, y'know, you can just get used to it by training.

> Also, you have to think about the material of the diving apparatus and pumping machine. Wouldn't they also crush at high pressures underwater?

They'd only be crushable if they were weak and gas-filled. We can put submarines at the bottom of the challenger deep, so clearly we can make gas-filled objects that can take the pressure.

Remember that when you have a [rebreather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebreather) you don't need as huge gas bottles as you would with an open-circuit gas supply system. Depending on your technology level, you may be able to obtain some or all of the oxygen demanded by the diver from the water (either via an artificial gill, or even just plain electrolysis) so the size of your gas reserves can be minimal. The rest of the system can be fluid-phase, and so more-or-less uncrushable.

(note that at extreme depths, cellular metabolism will break down as the various different components of your cells will compress at slightly different rates. there will be a maximum survivable depth for unprotected humans, though I have no idea what it would be other than "very deep")